# Can not call JavascriptSerialize on custom class

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a graph object, that I need to serialize. Nomatter which members i implement, the method returns `{}`

```
string json = new JavascriptSerializer().Serialize(routeGraph);
```

Here is my graph class:

```
namespace GraphClass
{
    [Serializable, DataContract]
    public class Graph : ISerializable
    {
        [DataMember]
        readonly Dictionary<string, Node> nodeMap = new Dictionary<string, Node>();
        [DataMember]
        private Tuple<string, string, double> bufferOriginalOffer;
    }
    [Serializable, DataContract]
    public class Node : ISerializable
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<Edge> Adj { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Node Prev { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double Distance { get; set; }
    [Serializable, DataContract]
    public class Edge : IComparable, ISerializable
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Node Destination { get; private set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double Cost { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public double Time { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable, DataContract]
    public class Tuple<T, T1, T2> : ISerializable
    {
        [DataMember]
        public T Item1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public T1 Item2 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public T2 Item3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tried for a whole day, to serialize this to either JSON or XML, as I have to send the object to a webservice.

**UPDATE:**
Used `DataContractJsonSerialiser` instead. I get the following error:

```
Object graph for type 'GraphClass.Edge' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.
```

As you can see in the Node class, a Node can contain a list of edges. I'm at a loss about fixing the error though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you perhaps intend to use `DataContractJsonSerializer` ? This is more data-contract oriented; `JavascriptSerializer` doesn't really care *at all* about data-contracts - it just looks at the type meta.

`Graph` only has private fields; `JavascriptSerializer` only looks at public members. Add a public property for `nodeMap`, perhaps?

Note that `[Serializable]` does nothing here, and those types **don't** implement `ISerializable` etc, despite claiming to.

---

Edit: confirmed the following seems to work OK:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(graph.GetType());
string s;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    ser.WriteObject(ms, graph);
    s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
}
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

and the following seems to work after adding a property:

```
public Dictionary<string, Node> NodeMap { get { return nodeMap; } }
...
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string s = ser.Serialize(graph);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Ah, I should use DataContractJsonSerializer then. But I am getting this error:
Object graph for type 'GraphClass.Edge' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.
If I use JavascriptSerializer, I get this error:
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type  Graph.Node

Comment: @CasperT graphs with loops are a pain to serialize. I can't diagnose without more detail though.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by loops, as it is a datastructure. Nodes can contain 1...* Edges, if that is what you mean. Which details do you need?

Comment: @CasperT - basically, any route through the graph that goes A => B => A. Most serializers are *tree* serializers, not graph serializers. This often means disabling thing like "Parent" properties (i.e. not marking them for serialization, or explicitly mark them as *ignored* from serialization). In your case, the "Prev" is looking highly suspect; do you need that serialized? Another common approach is to serialize a **simpler** model; less object-orientated, and more *data*-centric. Another way to look at it is: "how would **I** write this by hand?"

Comment: Yes. I do. I have 2 servers, one is a master another is a slave. I need the master to "feed" the slave with with it graph. making the slave basically own a "replicate", so everything has to be serialized.
I guess I will try find a different solution. You did answer my question though, of how I should handle the situation. So I'll accept your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Marc is exactly right here.  JavaScriptSerializer creates Json graphs based on the public properties of an object; of which your Graph class has none.  To use the DataContract features, you need the DataContractJsonSerializer.